# Matplotlib Line2D unexpected behavior

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

This is a minimum working example. I expect the following code to draw a line from (-2.33,10) to (4.33,-10), but the line I get is totally different. What is wrong?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.axis((-10,10,-10,10))
line = matplotlib.lines.Line2D((-2.33,10.0),(4.33,-10.0))
ax.add_line(line)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: have you had a look in the docs? You actually draw a line from (-2.33, 4.33) to (10,-10), as described in the docstring.

Comment: Silly of me, sorry. I read the docs, but somehow overlooked this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have given line2D `(x1, y1),  (x2, y2)`,  but you need to give it `(x1, x2),  (y1, y2)`

```
line = matplotlib.lines.Line2D((-2.33,4.33),(10,-10.0))
```